# how to not use N in TSQL when insert XML UTF 16

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, utf-16

I would like to know if it's possible to not use N prefix in TSQL when inserting UTF16 XML ?
Because i have a new version of my DB which in I change a NTEXT column's type to XML.
With NTEXT format, all previous software can insert row without using N Prefix successfully.
But now with XML column's type, when i try to insert XML with utf16, i get the conversion error.
So i fix the problem by using the N prefix into the new software version. But i would like all previous software continue to insert successfully.

Is there a solution ? maybe by change the column collation (never did this) ?

Thanx for your help

Hi,
I add example here.
Example from old software

```
INSERT INTO [myTable] ([id], [xmldata]) VALUES (1, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><viewlist version="3">....</viewlist>')
```

example from new software

```
    INSERT INTO [myTable] ([id], [xmldata]) VALUES (1, N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><viewlist version="3">....</viewlist>')
```

Comment: `With NTEXT format, all previous software can insert row without using N Prefix successfully` - which means you never actually had data that could benefit from Unicode. Yes, you absolutely should use `N` when inserting string literals into either `ntext` or `xml` columns.

Comment: `ntext` and `text` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)` or `varchar(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: I think about a trigger to add unicode to the string given, but i don't find any solution to convert the string to unicode into the trigger :(

Comment: If a string has already been provided as a non-unicode string, adding N inside the query will do absolutely nothing. The character data has been destroyed.

Comment: The problem is with new software version when columns is XML typed. Old software insert XML with utf16 prolog which didn't cause trouble with NTEXT columns

Answer (score -2):

(1) Usually, and depending on your character set, you can safely remove N'...' prefix. SQL Server will do it implicitly, as XML data type is stored as UTF-16.

(2) If your XML does contain UNICODE characters, the N'...' on the T-SQL level is mandatory.

SQL Server strips any XML prolog declarations. Like `'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>`. If you will query back the inserted XML, you will see that the prolog is gone.

Though you might be inserting XML via different means: middle-tier application, SSIS, bcp, etc. The rules are different all the time.

You should edit your original post and share a couple of real examples of how you are inserting the XML.

Comment: Please compare the results of `select cast('<a>☺</a>' as xml)` and `select cast(N'<a>☺</a>' as xml)`.

Comment: @GSerg The smiley face was the perfect choice.

Comment: @GSerg, I agree with the humor. Let's wait for the op's T-SQL example.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Actually the humor is just a side product. The main reason why the face was chosen is so that it's not a character from any national codepage. Otherwise you might have gotten same results with the two code snippets and argue that it's fine after all.

Comment: @GSerg, your comments above are reflecting the op scenario: 
"...With NTEXT format, all previous software can insert row without using N Prefix successfully - which means you never actually had data that could benefit from Unicode..."

Comment: @GSerg, Trying to promote XML technologies, I recently asked Microsoft to beef up NoSQL functionality in SQL Server.

Please check it out, add your comments, and **vote** for it:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38142115-sql-server-vnext-post-2019-and-nosql-functionali

Comment: Actually, i never had UNICODE in this column at this time. But for a new client, i will.

Comment: @oliviersow, your latest comment changes everything. While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Without it, it makes a question and any answer opinion based. I updated the answer.